# Get days passed and days left in current month with HANA SQL

Tags: sql, hana

I am able to calculate the number of days passed but don't really know how to get the number of days left in the current month.

Not counting today, it should come under days left.

```
SELECT (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1) AS DAYSPASSED,
<Insert Logic here> AS DAYSLEFT
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

As of today DAYSPASSED should be 26 and DAYSLEFT should be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use LAST_DAY function and subtract the current day of month

```
SELECT (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1) AS DAYSPASSED,
       LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) + 1  AS DAYSLEFT
 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Comment: I had to modify a little, but it works. Thanks !!

SELECT (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1) AS DAYSPASSED,
       DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)) - DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) + 1  AS DAYSLEFT
 FROM TEST_TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer by George Joseph you might as well use the DAYS_BETWEEN() function:

```
SELECT (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1) AS DAYSPASSED
, DAYS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE))+1 AS DAYSLEFT
FROM TEST_TABLE
```